# events consumed many times by kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Events are being consumed many times in kafka. These are the configs, what is the error. I am not able to find.

```
producer:
  isIdempotent: true
  acknowledgementMode: all
  requestTimeout: 2000
  retries: 100
  deliveryTimeout: 120000
  maxBlockTimeout: 15000
  isSync: false
  maxInFlightRequestsPerConnection: 5
consumer:
  pollTimeOut: 1000
  maxPollInterval: 300000
  batchSize: 1
```

Maybe the issue is in configs

Comment: Need more information. Is your producer sending events multiple times? How are you checking they're the same? Kafka doesn't de-duplicate identical records. Did you print out the consumed record offsets?

Comment: producer is sending one time only

Comment: did not print the consumed record offsets

Comment: So, if you do print the offsets, are those duplicated, or not? Can you share your consumer code?

Comment: offsets are not duplicate

Comment: Again, please share your consumer code with an [edit]